# Angular 1.6 typeError with binding

Tags: angularjs

New with angular and getting this error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '$ctrl' in subpackage

I have a parent and a child component where I have this function on the parent that I use to filter some JSON to get a certain value. I am getting stuck in what to do in the child controller so I can call this parent function and haven't even begun to figure out what I need to do to call this from the child template. Here is what I have.

```
var myApp = angular.module('subPackages', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);


(function (app) {
    'use strict';

    app.component('appComponent', {
        templateUrl: '../subpackages/templates/app-template.html',
        controller: subAppController
    });


    app.component('perfList', {
        templateUrl: '../subpackages/templates/perf-list.templateV3.html',
        controller: PerfListController,
        bindings: {
            contentJson: '<',
            getGlobalContent: '&'
        },
    });

})(myApp);
```

Parent

```
function subAppController() {

    this.currentStep = 1;


    this.contentJson = 
    {
        "id": "1",
        "cart_method": "cartAdd",
        "package": "69",
        "page_title": "Subscriptions",
        "page_header": "Choose a minimum of 3 performances\/events for guaranteed subscriber prices throughout the season.<\/br>\r\nStep 1: Choose your performances and price sections. Step 2: Indicate your seating preference.",
        "add_btn_txt": "Add"
    }

    this.globalContentJson = [
            { "id": "1", "module": "subpackage", "item": "mobileNavText", "content": "Month Navigation" },
            { "id": "2", "module": "subpackage", "item": "allPerfText", "content": "All Performances" },
            { "id": "3", "module": "subpackage", "item": "pageTopText", "content": "BACK TO TOP" },
            { "id": "4", "module": "subpackage", "item": "cartSummaryText", "content": "Your Selections" },
            { "id": "5", "module": "subpackage", "item": "cartSummaryRemoveText", "content": "Delete" },
            { "id": "6", "module": "subpackage", "item": "continueBtnText", "content": "Continue" }
    ];



    //Called from the template to get global content.
    this.getGlobalContent = function (module, item) {
        var globalContent = new contentProvider(this.globalContentJson);
        var result = globalContent.get(module, item);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Parent Template

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="cs-app-left row">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <label>{{$ctrl.contentJson.page_title}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="cs-app-right pull-right">          
            <cart-summary
             content-json="$ctrl.contentJson">

            </cart-summary>
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="cs-app-main row">
        <div>
            <perf-list 
                       ng-if="$ctrl.currentStep == 1" 
                       content-json="$ctrl.contentJson"
                       get-global-content="$ctrl.getGlobalContent(module,item)"
                    >

            </perf-list>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

child controller

```
function PerfListController() {
this.$onInit = function () {
    this.content = this.contentJson;
    this.globalContent = this.getGlobalContent;

    var cartAddEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('.cs-cartadd'));
    var redirectEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('.cs-redirect'));

    if (this.content.cart_method == "cartAdd") {
        cartAddEl.removeClass('hidden');
        redirectEl.addClass('hidden');
    } else {
        redirectEl.removeClass('hidden');
        cartAddEl.addClass('hidden');
    }
    this.cart_method = this.content.cart_method;

    this.test = this.globalContent("subpackage", "mobileNavText");
};
//Other Code Here
}
```

Comment: a little confused, why do you need the function in the child controller if your just calling it in the init method? Why not just pass it the data?

Comment: Sorry, not following you here. Are you saying instead of bringing down the function into the child component just call the function from the parent in the child template? Again, I am sorry. very new at this.

Comment: I'm wondering if you need the function in both the parent and the child controller. Are you doing anything with the data from the function in both the parent and child?

Comment: No I am not. Just static data that is used by both templates. No updates to the data. The data is this.globalContentJson. I just need to be able to filter it down to a particular value. Such as, <div>{{ I need the the content value where module = subpackage and item = mobileNavText }} </div>

Comment: Avoid doing DOM manipulation in controllers. Use the [ng-class directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to dynamically set classes. Also consider using the [ng-hide directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) to hide elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved. Was calling the function wrong in the child template. Ended up using

```
<span>
   {{$ctrl.globalContent({module: "subpackage", item:"mobileNavText"})}}
</span>
```

Thanks for the advice georgeawg on the classes, I will modify them.